# Git Gui for remote repository (PHP Developing)

Tags: php, git

I know similar questions have been aksed here, but i cant find one for my specific question.

We need Git for version control on a php projekt.
We have a Git repository on our server in which the php and html files are under version control, for debugging puprpose we can access the work tree of this repository through apache and display the output.
Now we have a bare Git Repository from which we pull changes to the development repository and the developers push their changes to this repository.

The developers itself also need to debug their code through the apache before they push to the central repo, so their working copys also need to be on the server.

My question is, is there a way for the developing theme to use a Git Gui to manage their remote repositorys on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install a minimal subset of X and Tk libraries on your development server
and then use SSH to port-forward X connection from it to the developers' machines. If these are running Windows you have to install a local X server on them ([VcXsrv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv) is an excellent choice), and if these are running systems having true X server, <s>you'd need to configure the X server to listen on TCP (IIRC, most contemporary systems come with this setting disabled by default).</s> `ssh -X` handles X port-forwarding just fine no matter how the local X server is configured to run.

How to configure port forwarding, depends on what client you're using. PuTTY has GUI configurator for this, OpenSSH supports ad-hoc configuration using command-line options of "static" via the `RemoteForward` configuration file directive.

Google for `X`+`window`+`SSH`+`port`+`forwarding` for lots of HOWTOs. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) appears to be a good start.

---

But really I fail to see what's wrong with learning a bit of command-line Git.  It allows to do the same things `git gui` can (including interactive hunk-by-hunk staging), and more. As to learning material, all Git books and HOWTOs and blog posts cite command-line Git examples anyway.

In the end, I think it's a good investment anyway: this could make your devs more productive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Theres nothing wrong with command-line git, but i just wanted to see if there is an GUI solution also available, because it is much more comfortable especially when it comes to merge-conflict handling.

Comment: git command line is fine for some things but when trying to visualize the commit tree, resolve merge conflicts, or even write a multi-line commit comment, it's terrible and no 'learning command line' will get around that.

Comment: @ChrisDragon, `git log --graph` works just fine for commit visualization; I have an alias `git overview` which does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` to do that ;-) But actually my point rather was that learning how do to certain things in CLI could ease working remotely (via bare SSH), and possibly make certain things easier locally. I'm not opposed to GUIs.